# function for click on images to display the url

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a form that holds a loop of images to choose from. In order to eventually make an ajax post call, I need to get the url of an image when it's clicked.

Within the form, where the loop of image is, I have a script block that is using an onclick function for the image, but when I click the image (using 'test' or 'good' in the console log) I'm not getting any response in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form action="changeImage.php" method="post">
    <?php foreach($imageResult as $im): ?>
      <?php if($im['type'] == 'background' ) {?>
        <img class="backgroundImage" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>">
      <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $page['id']?>">

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var BgImg = document.getElementsByClassName('backgroundImage');
       BgImg.onclick = function(){console.log(<URL here>)};  
    </script>
 </form>
```

Comment: You need to loop through your `HTMLCollection` and in the loop attach your event.

Comment: Script47 is referring to `document.getElementsByClassName` which returns an array-like collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document.getElementsByClassName()` Returns an array. You need to loop through it to access objects returned.

Try setting your `onclick` call inside the div element so you won't have problems with loading sequence of javascript and also why loop twice?*.

`<img class="backgroundImage" onclick='click()' style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>">`

And then in your `<script></script>` tag, create the click function that is invoked when element is clicked.

You will automatically get an event object passed inside the function. there you can access the target element and it's attrs.

it should look something like this:

```php
<form action="changeImage.php" method="post">
  <?php foreach($imageResult as $im): ?>
    <?php if($im['type'] == 'background' ) {?>
      <img class="backgroundImage" onclick='click()' style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo $im['url'] ?>">
    <?php } ?>
  <?php endforeach ?>

  <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $page['id']?>">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function click() {
      console.log(event.target.getAttribute('src'));
    } 
  </script>
</form>
```

you can also do it as you wanted if you put it in a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener (pure js for jquerys `$(document).ready()` so it sets your logic on loaded dom).

like this:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var BgImg = document.getElementsByClassName('backgroundImage');
    BgImg.map(img => {
      img.onclick = function(){console.log(event.target.getAttribute('src'))};
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So, I've tried this both ways, but specifically your first example. It gives no errors but still no console logging when I click the images

Comment: @TomN. My bad. getting the event inside the function. you don't need to pass `e` as an arg for event. it will automaticaly be as `event` var. like this:  `function click() {
      console.log(event.target.getAttribute('src'));
    } ` i've edited my answer